# Powershell send images in numerical order

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am looking to send an email via powershell that contains an image from a security camera. Every time the security camera senses movement it takes a picture and labels it using `{yyyy-MM-dd_H-mm-ss}.jpg` as the name. How can I send these pictures ordered by the name? I can also change the name to automatically increasing counter for each picture. Any incite would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code have you attempted to run? What errors did you encounter on your journey?

Comment: the code ive tried and has been unsuccessful im pretty new t using stacked overflow but this is the link ive ried to use                                                       https://www.seriouslytrivial.com/2015/04/19/ispyconnect-e-mail-alerts-without-the-paid-subscription-part-deux/

Comment: Please _edit the question instead adding a comment_ and explain how the shared article didn't help you. For example, did it send wrong images? No images at all? Are there any error messages? What do those say?